# Limit of positive function, bounded with derivative and convergent improper integral

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, improper-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to ask about marked place in Proposition 9 from N.H. Duu, *On The Existence of Bounded Solutions for Lotka- Volterra Equations*, Acta Mathematica Vietnamica 25(2) (2000), 145-159.

[image: prop 9]

Why limit of positive function which has convergent improper integral and its  bounded with derivative equal $0$?
I found some similar topic [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836043/limits-at-infinity-of-a-function-with-convergent-improper-integral). What's the point of bounded derivative according to proposition from article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are well-known counterexamples where $f$ is positive with a convergent improper integral over, say, $[0,\infty)$ and an unbounded derivative such that $f(x) \not\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Suppose though that the derivative is bounded and there exists $B$ such that $|f'(x)| < B$ for all $x$.  Then we must have $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Otherwise, we could find $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $f(x_n) \geqslant \epsilon$ and $x_{n+1} - x_n > \epsilon/(2B)$.  By the MVT, we have $f(x) = f(x_n) + f'(c_n)(x - x_n)$ with $x_n < c_n < x < x_n + \epsilon$ and

$$f(x) > \epsilon - B\epsilon / (2B)= \epsilon/2$$

Hence,

$$\int_{x_1}^\infty f(x) \, dx > \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{x_n}^{x_n+\epsilon/(4B)}f(x) \, dx > \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon^2}{8B} = +\infty,$$

which contradicts the assumption that the improper integral is convergent.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks. But what about continuous function? Same reasoning as for sequences?

Comment: Since $f$ is assumed to be differentiable it is also continuous.  What do you mean by "same reasoning as for sequences"?  This is the proof that if $f$ is differentiable (and, hence, continuous) with a bounded derivative and convergent improper integral on $[a,\infty)$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: The introduction of the sequence $x_n$ is how we carry out the proof by contradiction.  If the limit is not $0$ then there must be some sequence $x_n$ with the above properties, i.e., $f(x_n)$ stays bounded away from $0$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, everything is now clear. Thank you for your help!